# Java - Do you want to continue?(Y/N)

Tags: java, loops, repeat, continue

I want to write a simple loop for the program to go back and restart it again.

Just a simple 1 question program. Then the system ask if the user want to do it again. If the user inputs Y ... the program will loop it back to the beginning and run the entire program again. If the user inputs N, it exits.

```
import java.util.Scanner; // show them as code

public class HowToDoLoop {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("How much money do you want to have? ");
    double money = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Ok, here is yours $" + money);

    System.out.println("Do you want to continue y or n");
```

Comment: `while(true){ break; /* if no */ }`

Comment: Look into a `while`/ `do-while` loop

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because: ["3. Questions asking for homework help must include a **summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem**, and a **description of the difficulty you are having** solving it."](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Current state of your question doesn't fulfill these requirements. Use [edit] option to improve it.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html

Comment: Thank you for everyone's help! Pshemo, this is actually not part of my homework. I'm learning on my own. I watched some youtube videos and kind have a general idea about while loop. I just didn't know what syntax to use to accept Y or N.

Comment: *I watched some youtube videos*   I suggest reading a book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String c = "";
do{
    System.out.println("How much money do you want to have? ");
    double money = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Ok, here is yours $" + money);

    System.out.println("Do you want to continue y or n");
    c = input.nextLine();

}while(c.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));
```

Comment: Hey, add a semicolon at the end of the do-while loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
while(true){

    System.out.println("How much money do you want to have? ");
    double money = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Ok, here is yours $" + money);

    System.out.println("Do you want to continue y or n");
    String c = input.nextLine();

   if(c.equalsIgnoreCase("n")){ 
      break;
     }//else continue to loop on any string ;-)

}
```

Comment: answer.equalsIgnoreCase("n") .... this is the syntax I was looking for.